# Cakephp - Jquery JSOn Ajax call doesn't send any data after some idle time

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, jquery-1.4

Nevermind, I just figured out that CakePHP had to re-set the cookie because it expired. If you experience the same error, just check the return header with Firebug => "Set-Cookie".

---

I have a jquery function which calls a CakePHP Function with Ajax and returns it as JSON:

```
$('#categories a').live('click', function() {
    catid = $(this).attr('id');
    load_notes(catid);  
    return false;
});

function load_notes(catid){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/notes/load_notes',
            data: 'category_id='+catid,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                jQuery.each(data, function(i) {
                    new_note = '';
                    new_note = build_note(this.Note.id, this.Note.content);  
                    new_note.appendTo('#notes').hide().fadeIn(i*300);
                    //new_note.appendTo('#notes').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                    //new_note.appendTo('#notes');
                });

            },
            error:function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
}
```

"load_notes" is called after the document is ready and if I click on a Category-Link. This works fine when I just loaded the page or when I click on a category-link after a few minutes. But when I wait for around 30 minutes and fire the function, nothing is returned (therefore the notes can't be displayed).
Only if I reload the page, the function works fine again.

I usually get a JSON-Array as a response (checked with Firebug) but when the error occurs, I only get:

> "j is null" handleError(a=Object {
>   url="/notes/load_notes", global=true,
>   more...}, b=XMLHttpRequest {
>   onreadystatechange=[xpconnect wrapped
>   nsIDOMEventListener], readyState=4,
>   more...}, d="success", e=null)

Any clue what could cause this? Anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Is this ajax call attached to a dom object? For example, if you just include this code in a regular $(document).ready(function(){... wrapper, it will be executed when the dom has finished loading. However, if you attach it to something like $('a').click(function() {$.ajax({... then it will be fired every time a link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a firebug problem, not jquery. I get this same error with firebug sometimes (fully randomly) and it solves when I restart the browser.

Maybe is a stupid question but.. have you tried with other browsers / consoles?? With Chrome I haven't had this problem again.